# Filter model without using distinct method

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a list of products. Each product has an ID, price, brand, etc. I want return all the objects of the model where brand name is distinct. I am currently using django's built-in SQLite, so it does not support something like

```
products = Product.objects.all().distinct('brand')
```

Is there another way of returning all the objects where the brand name is distinct?

Comment: That question is a bit ambiguous. Do you want a list of brands?  Or one (any?) product of each brand?

Comment: I want a list of all the objects in the product model, but I don't want objects with the same brand name. So if I have 10 objects in Product and 3 of them have the Brand of "Brand A", I want to return 8 objects and all of their other attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SQLight doesn't support `.distinct('field')` you need to do this directly in python. For example:

```
products = list({p.brand: p for p in Product.objects.all()}.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it with 2 different methods:

1. def MethodName(self):

   ```
   query = """
        SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM Product;
        """
   self.execute(query)
   ```

   2. products = Product.objects.raw("""
      SELECT DISTINCT brand FROM Product;
      """)

Please reply to this message If you have any difficulties fetching.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so try

```
distinctBrands = Product.objects.values('brand').annotate(count=Count('brand')).filter(count=1)

products = Products.objects.filter(
    brand__in=distinctBrands 
).all()
```

Comment: That eliminates brands that have more than one product

Comment: isn't that what they want? from "I want return all the objects of the model where brand name is distinct."

Comment: Apparently not. See the clarifying comment from OP. But yes, it's hard to understand from the question.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
products = set(Product.objects.values_list('brand'))
```

Comment: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

Comment: Hopefully now this will work.